# Clarification on statistical notation of mutual information

Tags: entropy, information-theory, notation, definition, mutual-information

> **Definition**: The *conditional mutual information* of random variables $X$ and $Y$ given $Z$ is:
>
> $$I(X;Y|Z) := H(X|Z)-H(X|Y,Z)\,.$$

where $H$ is the entropy.

**Question:** I am not sure what is meant by the expressions $I(X;Y|Z)$ and $H(X|Y,Z)$ -- does one consider first the joint distribution and then condition, or vice versa? Is there a convention for interpreting this kind of notation in general?

**Attempt:**

- My interpretation of $I(X;Y|Z)$ is *the mutual information of the random variable X given the parameter Y given Z.* $$I(X;(Y|Z)), \quad \text{ not } \quad I((X;Y)|Z)\,.$$
- My interpretation of $H(X|Y,Z)$ is *the entropy of the random variable X given the joint random variables Y and Z.* $$H(X|(Y,Z)),\quad\text{ not }\quad H((X|Y),Z)\,.$$

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I belive that the second one is correct, but that the first is incorrect. I.e. we are not considering the (unconditional) mutual information of random variables $X$ and $Y|Z$ (indeed, there is no definition in probability theory of a "conditional random variable" $Y|Z$), this is an entirely new definition which is meant to be analogous to the concept of (unconditional) mutual information, at least as far as I understand.

Comment: Thus, in terms of general convention, it is always $(X,Y)|Z$ and $X|(Y,Z)$, since there is no such thing as "conditional random variables" $Y|Z$ or $X|Y$. If you don't believe me, try to answer this: how can one make sense of the question: "what is the probability that $X|Y=a$?". The question: "what is the probability that $X=b$ given that $Y=c$?" makes sense, but the previous question doesn't. This isn't a proof, but just an intuitive argument for why you should expect that the expressions $X|Y$ and $Y|Z$ don't define random variables -- thus there is actually no ambiguity in the notation.